# Set commentDirectivesEnabled and cssClassDirectivesEnabled to false in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to make some small tweaks to my config to hopefully improve performance slightly. I read through the Angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) and they mention disabling comment and CSS class directives. I tried to do so with the below code in my config, but I keep getting `TypeError: $compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled is not a function` or `TypeError: $compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled is not a function` errors.

Note: I'm running Angular 1.4.9

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .config(compilationConfig)
;

compilationConfig.$inject = ['$compileProvider'];

function compilationConfig($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
  $compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled(false);
  $compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved this myself. This functionality was introduced in 1.6.0 so you need to upgrade to take advantage of these methods.

Comment: Just ran into this myself. It's introduced in 1.6.0 which is still RC. Not sure why the docs default to an RC version you'd expect them to default to latest stable...

Comment: I am using 1.5.5 and getting the same error. Any idea why?